# NestJS lazy loading a module importing TypeORM doesn't register "Connection" providers

Tags: nestjs, lazy-loading, typeorm

I have a `DatabaseModule` that imports TypeORM and starts the db connections (cf. `database.module.ts`).
I use that module on a crud module and everything works fine while registring the modules the classical way.

But when **I lazy load that same module, it breaks and I get the "Can't resolve Connection" error.**

> "ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] Nest can't resolve dependencies of the ProductRepository (?). Please make sure that the argument Connection at index [0] is available in the TypeOrmModule context."

(*I'm writing serverless functions, hence the lazy-loading attempt.*)

```js
// product.module.ts: the module I lazy-load
@Module({
imports: [
  DatabaseModule.register({
    entities: [Product],
  }),
],
```

```js
// database.module.ts: the module that creates the db connections
export interface DatabaseOptions {
  entities: any[];
}

@Module({})
export class DatabaseModule {
  static register(options: DatabaseOptions): DynamicModule {
    return {
      module: DatabaseModule,
      imports: [
        TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
          type: 'mysql',
          host: '0.0.0.0',
          port: 3306,
          username: 'root',
          password: '****',
          database: 'example',
          retryAttempts: 5,
          synchronize: true,
          entities: options.entities,
        }),
        TypeOrmModule.forFeature(options.entities),
      ],
      providers: [],
      exports: [TypeOrmModule],
    };
  }
}
```

Here is the lazy loading part.

```js
// app.controller.ts
@Get()
async createProduct(): Promise<Product> {
  // Lazy load the module that imports the DatabaseModule to lazy-load the connections.
  const { ProductModule } = await import('./product/product.module');
  const productModule = await this.lazyModuleLoader.load(() => ProductModule);
  const { ProductService } = await import('./product/product.service');
  // It breaks here, 'Connection' providers are not registered.
  const productService = productModule.get(ProductService);

  return productService.create();
}
```

Once again, **it works fine when I register the `ProductModule` in the main `AppModule`**, so I **expected the module to work the same way with lazy-loading**.

I guess I have to lazy load more stuff for this to work, but I can't understand why the Connection / Repository providers are not available when I lazy-load the product module...

[Reproduction repo](https://github.com/Kapcash/nestjs-lazy-typeorm-reproduce)
(There is a docker-compose with a mysql image to debug locally).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I faced the same problem, unfortunately. I've got it working via the `ASYNC_CONNECTION` provider:

```js
import { ConnectionOptions, createConnection, getConnection } from 'typeorm';

providers: [{
  provide: 'ASYNC_CONNECTION',
  inject: [ConfigService],
  useFactory: async (configService: ConfigService) => {
    const { host, port, username, password, database } = configService.get('db');

    const connection: ConnectionOptions = {
      type: 'postgres',
      host,
      port,
      username,
      password,
      database,
      name: 'custom',
      entities: [...entities],
      synchronize: false,
      namingStrategy: new SnakeNamingStrategy(),
    };

    try {
      getConnection(connection.name);
    } catch (error) {
      return await createConnection(connection);
    }
  }
}]
```

Then you can inject the `ASYNC_CONNECTION` provider wherever you want:

```js
@Inject('ASYNC_CONNECTION')
private connection: Connection,
```

And use the classic repository approach with the entities you've declared above:

```js
this.connection.getRepository(<Entity>).findOne({})
```

That's it.

Comment: Thanks this approach is good enough, using for providing microservices(client) in lazy loading sub module too; providing once in app module of client and injecting by TOKEN (this approach) in sub lazy loading modole

Comment: @Kapcash how do you handle the lazy loaded part with the async provider?, I dont know how to inject the provider `token` to access the connection on demand